# select a random order of a customer

Tags: sql, hana

I have a table of customer and their orders. i would like to select a random order of each customer.

Example table

```
customer | orders
---------+---------
customerA| Order1
customerA| Order2
CustomerA| Order3
customerB| Order1
customerB| Order2
customerB| Order3
CustomerC| Order1
customerC| Order2
```

result table

```
customer | orders
---------+---------
customerA| Order2
customerB| Order1
CustomerC| Order1
```

Is there way?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` (and ANSI standard function).  However, calculating the random number varies by database.  Here is the idea:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer order by random()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Some random number functions:

- SQL Server:  `newid()`
- Postgres:    `random()`
- Oracle:      `dbms_random.value`
- Teradata:    `random(1, 999999999)`
- DB2:         `rand()`
- SAP Hana:    `rand()`

Comment: thanks its working.  Could you please explain the use of `where seqnum = 1`? is it mean the first row?

Comment: @Sai . . . That means the first row in each group of orders for a customer.  The orders are randomly sorted, so "first" doesn't refer to some specific row.

Comment: I didnt knew that we can order a table by `random()` thats really awesome @Gordon!